# Removing a source in mapbox gl js doesn't remove its layers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to selectively remove a source in mapbox gl js, I'm using `map.removeSource('<SOURCE_ID>')` but nothing happens. The layers still remain on the map. I've created an example in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMNVQW?editors=1010#anon-login).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You've got to remove the source and the layer. Call removeLayer first (since it depends on the source) and then remove the source next.

Comment: I believe I have removed the layer already, but the source seems to be in use still. Is there any way to see what layer is using a source by chance?

Comment: how to call removeLayer

Comment: Is there any progress? I'm still confronted with the same problem. Even after removing the Layer it says ```Source '<source layer name>' is in use, cannot remove```